# Nodejs array push is empty when placed after await

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to loop through an array, get the quantity and prices of each stock from the database, do some calculations and push them to an array

But after getting the quantity and prices from the database and push to the array

The array will still be empty

If I remove this line

```
const db_stock = await Stocks.findById(stock.stockId);
```

everything works fine

But if I add the await back the array becomes empty

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { response } from "express";
import  StockDispatches  from "../models/StockDispatch.js"
import  Stocks  from "../models/Stocks.js"
import { createError } from "../error.js";
import validator from 'express-validator'
const { validationResult } = validator
import { generateRamdom } from "../utils/Utils.js"

export const createStockDispatched = async (req, res, next) => {
    
  
    const error = validationResult(req).formatWith(({ msg }) => msg);
    const trx_id =  generateRamdom(30);
    let quantity = 0;
    let total = 0;
    let dispatchedTotal = 0;
    const hasError = !error.isEmpty();

    if (hasError) {
      res.status(422).json({ error: error.array() });
    } else {
        

        const options={ordered: true}; 
        let user_stocks =[];
        req.body.stocks.map(async (stock, index) => {
            let total = stock.price * stock.quantity

            const db_stock = await Stocks.findById(stock.stockId);
            if(!db_stock) return res.status(404).json({msg: "Stock Not Found."})
            
            if( stock.quantity > db_stock.quantity)
            return res.status(208).json({msg: `Quantity of ${stock.name} is greater than what we have in database`})

            quantity = db_stock.quantity - stock.quantity;
            total = quantity * db_stock.price;

            const updated_stock = await Stocks.findByIdAndUpdate(stock.id, {quantity, total},{$new: true})

            
            dispatchedTotal = stock.quantity * db_stock.price;
            user_stocks.push("samson")
            user_stocks.push({...stock, staffId: req.user.id, total: dispatchedTotal, trx_id, stockId: stock.id, price: db_stock.price})

        });
        
        

        try{
            const stockDispatched = await StockDispatches.insertMany(user_stocks, options);
            if(!stockDispatched) return res.status(500).json({msg: "Error. Please try again."})
            
            return res.status(200).json({msg: "Stock uploaded successfully.."})
        }catch(error){
            next(error)
        }
      
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhhh `.map()` is not promise-aware and does not block the loop for your `await` so you're just going to get an array of promises back from `req.body.stocks.map` which you need to wait for with `Promise.all()` so you know when everything is done.  Right now you're pretending that `.map()` is blocking and waiting for the promises you use in its callback when it's not.  Thus, you try to use `user_stocks` before it has any values in it.

Comment: Simplest suggestion is to change `req.body.stocks.map()` to `for (let [index, stock] of req.body.stocks.entries()) { ... }` since the `for` loop is promise-aware and will pause the loop for your `await` inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to change

```
req.body.stocks.map()
```

to:

```
for (let [index, stock] of req.body.stocks.entries()) { ... }
```

since the for loop is promise-aware and will pause the loop for your await inside the loop body whereas `.map()` does not pause its loop for an `await` in the callback.